# function multiple

Tags: bash

```
7zpar() {
7z t $1 && par2 c -r10 -u Recovery $1
}
```

I attempting to chain two commands in one through a function, and the first runs without issue, but the second never fires. I admit I am new to programming, and I have searched online to see if I am doing something wrong. So far, I haven't found anything regarding this.

Comment: `&&` makes the subsequent commands dependent on the success/failure of the previous command. If you want to the par2 command to run unconditionally, use a `;` instead.

Comment: Are there some special character in $1? It's safer to quote it like "$1".

Comment: No special characters. It's plain text from an array.

Answer (score 2):

Any reason not to just run the two without the `&&` check?

```
7zpar() {
7z t $1 
par2 c -r10 -u Recovery $1
}
```

`&&`, in the context you have it, will run the second command only if the first one returns success. Odds are `7z` is returning false and `par2` is never being run. Unless you *want* this behavior, just split it out.

Comment: Yeah, that was my intention; that it would run upon success of previous command.. and via console I can see the former command completing... oh well.

Comment: @Fred: `echo $?` after the `7z` command to see what its return value is.